# How to add numbers after drag and drop in container using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add some  numbers which i have drag and drop in some containers using jquery.

here is my html code

```
<div id="products">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Blocks</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ul>
                       <li data-id="1" class = "credit"> 400 </li>
            <li data-id="2"class = "credit"> 200</li>
            <li data-id="3" class = "credit"> 300 </li>
            <li data-id="4" class = "credit"> 500  </li>
               <li data-id="5" class = "credit"> 700  </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <tr><td>

<table border=1 width=100%>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="shoppingCart1" class="shoppingCart">
    <h7 class="ui-widget-header">no1</h7>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol style="list-style:none">
            <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
     </td>
            </tr>
</table>
        </td><td>

<table border=1 width=100%>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="shoppingCart1" class="shoppingCart">
    <h7 class="ui-widget-header">no2</h7>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
       <ol style="list-style:none" id="place2">
            <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
        </td></tr></table>
```

and my jquery code is

```
$("#products li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});
$("#shoppingCart1 ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
     containment: "document",
        revert: true,
        accept:".credit",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var self = $(this);
                     contents = $(this).attr('#shoppingCart1 ol li');
        self.find(".placeholder").remove();
        var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
        if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length) return;
        $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "data-id": productid
        }).appendTo(this);

        var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('id');
        $(".shoppingCart:not(#"+cartid+") [data-id="+productid+"]").remove();
    }
}).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
});
$("#shoppingCart2 ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept:".debit",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var self = $(this);
        self.find(".placeholder").remove();
        var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
        if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length) return;
        $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "data-id": productid
        }).appendTo(this);
        var contents=ui.draggable.text();
 //$("#list").attr( ui.draggable.text());


        // To remove item from other shopping chart do this
        var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('id');
        $(".shoppingCart:not(#"+cartid+") [data-id="+productid+"]").remove();
    }
}).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
         $('#list').text('test');
    }
});
```

now prolem is i want to add this numbers after drag and drop so how can i do this.
here you can also see the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjayrathod/aNreg/40/

I am trying this till 4 hours and search entire internet but did not successed so please if anyone give me some sugestion then it will be appreciated.
thankyou and please help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aNreg/43/  Drag items into no1.  Is this what you mean?  If so I'll promote it to an answer so you can check it off.

Comment: No i mean after each drag and drop there should be addition of that number should be displayed. if i am drag and drop 400 and 200 then addition should be 600

Comment: That's what I'm doing.  If you drag 400 and 200 both to `no1` then it shows `600` below.  Are you saying it should add `no1` to `no2`?  If so, when you can drop multiple items, what's it supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks bro you have give me the way ... its correct thanks a lot

Comment: Ok great, I added my response as an answer so you can accept it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aNreg/43/

The code that does the adding is:

```
var sum = 0;
self.find('li').each(function(index)
             {
                 sum += parseInt($(this).text());
             });
$('#math1').text(sum);
```